# How to get all HTTP packet requests made by webview

Tags: android, http, android-webview

While loading a URL in webView there are multiple of HTTP request made while loading a single page. Is there a way to track those requests? The closest I could get is to use

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
```

method to view the URL requests made but could not capture the packets each page make.
I know this Question has already been asked years ago but couldn't find a solid answer that I can depend. Any help would be helpful

Comment: Do you want to get all urls when calling http request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override

`public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)`

method of WebViewClient. This will be called everytime javascript code requests any resource inside Webview.